# How are new tags generated in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, tags

How are new tags created by Stack Exchange? Can I create one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**Create new tags**](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) privilege requires 1500 rep. When you reach that, you can create tags by:

> **How do I create a new tag?**
>
> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> - have a maximum of 25 characters
> - must use the character set a-z 0-9 + # - .

Check out the [privileges help page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to see all the other wonderful things you will be able to do, as you gain reputation. The rep requirements are different per site, so make sure you check out the privileges help page on every site you are active on.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. On Stack Overflow, you need at least [1500](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) reputation to create tags.

It differs on different sites, though